# how to play video from URL on iwatch

Tags: video-streaming, avplayer, watchkit, avplayeritem

I made a simple video player on an iPhone app by using `AVPlayer`.

For the video view layer I use `AVPlayerLayer` and `UIImageView`.

```
...
[self.previewImage.layer addSublayer:self.mPlayerLayer];
...
```

But I can't find the solution for an iWatch app, `WKInterfaceImage` hasn't that feature.

I'm looking for a solution of video play on `iWatch`.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Watch (not iWatch) does not support playing video. You're not finding it for a reason.

Comment: To add to bgilham's answer, a not-ideal workaround is to send a lower quality series of animated images to the Watch. The problem is that the transmission time is a big limiting factor, and you won't have audio. Definitely not ideal.